# Redelivered task are getting populated in queue

Tags: python-3.x, rabbitmq, celery, scheduled-tasks, flask-celery

I am using celery version 5.1.2 (sun-harmonics) and rabbitmq as broker with rabbitmqadmin v3.12.4.

When asynchronous non-scheduled tasks are pushed to the queue and if these tasks take time to process(approx 5 minutes) then redelivered tasks are getting pushed to celery default queue/assigned queue for scheduled tasks.

Here is example of empty task with no args pushed in queue:

```
| celery | | 0 | [[], {}, { "callbacks": null, "errbacks": null, "chain": null, "chord": null } ]
```

I have added the `visibility_timeout` to 3600 seconds, but still it's getting redelivered tasks.

```
celery_automation_app = Celery(__name__, broker=get_broker_conn_str())
config_dir = get_argv_by_name()
app_config = AppConfig(config_dir)
celery_automation_app.conf.visibility_timeout = 3600
```